QML Error "modelData is not defined" when trying to display items read from Xml File
I read a xml file in the .cpp and save the items to a QVariantList. The debug statement in the .cpp prints the data ok. So I know the logic for reading the xml file is ok.
In the main.cpp I think I have created the link between .cpp file and .qml file correctly.
The issue is - In the .qml file the item data from xml file is not being displayed. I keep getting "ReferenceError: modelData is not defined". I expect rows of data in display.
qml_xmlitemsclass.h
class QML_XmlItemsClass : public QObject 
{
    Q_OBJECT    
    Q_PROPERTY(QVariantList ItemsTable_qvm READ getItemsTable_qvm WRITE setItemsTable_qvm NOTIFY updateItemsTable_qvm) 
        
    public:     
    Q_INVOKABLE QVariantList getItemsTable_qvm() const         { return ItemsTable; }       
    void        setItemsTable_qvm(const QVariantList &newh)    { if (ItemsTable != newh)  { ItemsTable = newh; emit updateItemsTable_qvm(); } }         
    
    signals:    
    void        updateItemsTable_qvm();         
    
    private:    
    QVariantList ItemsTable;          
}

qml_xmlitemsclass.cpp
    bool QML_XmlItemsClass::GetItems() 
    {
        QFile FileIn("//path to the xml file//");
        FileIn.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    
        QXmlStreamReader xmlReader(&FileIn);
        ItemsTable.clear();
    
        while (!xmlReader.atEnd() && !xmlReader.hasError())
        {
            xmlReader.readNext();
    
            // Only process elements that is of interest
            if (xmlReader.isStartElement() && xmlReader.name().toString() == "Data")
            {
                QVariantMap itemData;
    
                // The XML structure is like: <Data key="value" />
                foreach (const QXmlStreamAttribute &attr, xmlReader.attributes())
                {
                    itemData["key"] = attr.name().toString();
                    itemData["value"] = attr.value().toString();
                }
                ItemsTable.append(itemData); //itemDatais a private member of this class defined as 'QVariantList itemData;'
            }        
        }
    
        qDebug() << "TableData:" << ItemsTable; 
        setConfigurationTable_qvm(ConfigurationTable);
        return true; 
}

Main.cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "qml_xmlitemsclass.h"

QML_XmlItemsClass              QML_XmlItemsObj;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    qmlRegisterType<QML_ConfigurationClass>("QML_XmlItemsClass", 0, 1, "QML_XmlItemsClass");
    
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("QML_XmlItemsObj", &QML_XmlItemsObj);
    
    QObject::connect(
        &engine,
        &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreationFailed,
        &app,
        []() { QCoreApplication::exit(-1); },
        Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.loadFromModule("PS1724", "Main");    

    int ret = app.exec();
    
    return ret;
}

LoadXmlItems.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls.Basic

Item
{   
    id: theRoot
    height: 800; width: 1280;
    anchors.top: parent.top;
    
    Rectangle
    {
        id: availableItemsDisplayContainer
        anchors { left: parent.left; right: parent.right; margins: 3; }
        color: "#003951";
        height: 430;
        radius: 5;

        ListView
        {
            anchors.fill: parent
            model: QML_XmlItemsObj.ItemsTable_qvm
           
            delegate:
            Rectangle
            {
                required property int index

                width: ListView.view.width
                height: 40 // Set the height to avoid overlap between items
                color: index % 2 === 0 ? "#D5A824" : "#E3C15D" // Alternate row colors for better readability

                Row
                { // Use a Row to align the key and value horizontally
                    spacing: 10 // Add some space between the key and value text

                    Text
                    {
                        text: modelData["key"]                        
                        //text: "SampleKey"
                        color: "black"
                        font.pointSize: 12                        
                    }

                    Text
                    {
                        text: modelData["value"]
                        //text: "SampleValue"
                        color: "black"
                        font.pointSize: 12                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }        
}


Does it work if you first add required property string key to your delegate and then use it like this: text: key? I don't think you need modelData at all.
